# Can't access superclass private variable set to instance from other class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to make my own API that extends an old API. I have two files, *old_API* and my new *my_API*. I want to use all the functions in the API file, so I inherit from it. I can now use all functions contained within the inherited class. But I can't access the private class variables's functions of the super-class.

**old_API File**

```
class API:
   def __init__(self):
       self._foo = {}

    def add_Foo(self, arg):
        self._foo = Bar(self) # I need to access this instance 
        return self._foo[arg]

class Bar:
    def some_function(self, input: str):
    # This the function I want to use!
```

**my_API File**

```
class Baz(API):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Baz, self).__init__(self):

    def add_Foo(self, arg):
        super(Baz, self).add_Foo(self, arg)
```

**When using my_API**

```
from my_API import Baz

my_robot = Baz("Argument")
robot_foo = my_robot.add_Foo(arg)

robot_foo.some_function(input) # This does not work!
```

If I use the old API directly and do the same, it all works fine.

**When using old_API**

```
from old_API import API

my_robot = API("Argument")
robot_foo = my_robot.add_Foo(arg)

robot_foo.some_function(input) # This does work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
def add_Foo(self, arg):
    super(Baz, self).add_Foo(self, arg)
```

needs to return the return value of the call to `add_Foo`:

```
def add_Foo(self, arg):
    return super(Baz, self).add_Foo(self, arg)
```

Also I think that your method:

```
def add_Foo(self, arg):
    self._foo = Bar(self) # I need to access this instance 
    return self._foo[arg]
```

Should be:

```
def add_Foo(self, arg):
    self._foo[arg] = Bar(self) # I need to access this instance 
    return self._foo[arg]
```

Otherwise you would be replacing the dictionary with a Bar.

Answer (score 0):

You got `super()` wrong. It should be 
`super(Baz, self).add_Foo(self, arg)`. Read more at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: The super is the right way in my code, question corrected.